# Golang - printing the content of the variable

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and I am wondering how can I print the actual values of a struct that `doc.Find()` returns. I am using this [package](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) that has this methods.
So, for example if I do this:

```
casesCounter := doc.Find(".cases-counter li")
fmt.Printf("%T\n", casesCounter)
fmt.Println(&casesCounter)
fmt.Println(casesCounter)
```

I have also tried with using the pointer:

```
casesCounter := *doc.Find(".cases-counter li")
```

For each case I got memory addresses printed:

```
&{[0xc0004108c0 0xc000410b60] 0xc00023f720 0xc000230150}
{[0xc0004108c0 0xc000410b60] 0xc00023f720 0xc000230150}
```

But, how can I get the actual values of this struct, same as I when I would do `console.log()` in javascript?

Comment: Dereference the pointer with and ```*``` is one option

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I have tried putting * before doc.Find, but that gave me also memory address.

Comment: The return value casesCounter is what you want to manipulate. Try `fmt.Printf("%+v", *casesCounter)` (assuming casesCounter is a pointer since the current sample can not show that (use the go playground if you want to show a working example

Comment: yes, that was correct, thank you @NorbertvanNobelen

Comment: It always boils down to: You must read the documentation of what type doc.Find actually returns, then you handle this type properly, e.g. by dereferencing all pointers and invoking appropriate methods (often String()). For anything not-pointer formating works well with %#v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following code:

```
for _, v := range casesCounter.Nodes {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", v)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/blob/89946c829f29a2c154667e6194d4f409d8abcbde/traversal.go#L23), calling

```
doc.Find(selector string)
```

returns a pointer to the selection

You should therefore access the data through the selection, whose structure is [documented here](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/blob/master/type.go#L100)

I suppose you want to access the nodes, and as Latif mentioned, this can be done via a loop, as this is an array as documented above

```
for _, v := range casesCounter.Nodes {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", v)
}
```